# How to find the rows in a table that in specific columns contain value from another table in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a vector `a` with these elements:

```
ENSMUST00000000094 ENSMUST00000000137 ENSMUST00000000305 ENSMUST00000000349 ENSMUST00000000356 ENSMUST00000000384 ENSMUST00000000430 ENSMUST00000000449
```

and a data.frame `b` that in some of its rows have the elements from `a`.

The "b" is a data.frame with 2 columns:

```
gene <- c( "ENSMUSG00000026427(Lgtn)", "ENSMUSG00000026427(Lgtn)", "ENSMUSG00000026427(Lgtn)", "ENSMUSG00000055184(Fam72a)", ENSMUSG00000013275(Slc41a1)")
```

and

```
transcripts <- c("ENSMUST00000112446 ENSMUST00000149119 ENSMUST00000151874 ENSMUST00000068791 ENSMUST00000068805 ENSMUST00000131855 ENSMUST00000153651 ENSMUST00000086578", "ENSMUST00000149119 ENSMUST00000151874 ENSMUST00000068791 ENSMUST00000068805 ENSMUST00000131855 ENSMUST00000086578", "ENSMUST00000151874 ENSMUST00000068791 ENSMUST00000131855 ENSMUST00000086578", "ENSMUST00000068613
ENSMUSG00000052688(5430435G22Rik)
ENSMUST00000064679", "ENSMUST00000086559")

b <- cbind(gene, transcripts)
```

I want to find rows in "b" that in transcripts columns have one of the "a" elements.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Just convert a to a dataframe and merge

```
library(dplyr)

data_frame(transcripts = a) %>%
  left_join(b)
```